# figsize has no impact on Figures in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

this question is similar to others but in the end I can't find a way to make figsize works in Jupyter Notebook. I am probably missing something

I have a plot and I would like it to appear as a square.
However, it has a rectangular shape and I can't change it with figsize.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 6],[9, 4], "o")
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
```

I tried with and without the first line and I tried various numbers in figsize but nothing happens, my plot stays the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should set the figure size before you plot it. `plt.figure()` returns a figure which you can use for plotting later. Don't you get two plots with your code now? Also import do the magic command after the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert:

```
plt.axes([1, 1, .7, 1])
```

before your plot (below the import), this will set the axis of the plot, and you can play around with the numbers to make it larger/smaller

The axes is specified by: [left, bottom, width, height]

Comment: This doesn't really help explain specifically about the `figsize` argument and why it doesn't seem to affect the output in OP's environment.  While it's helpful that it accomplishes a goal, it does not explain the issue faced by the OP.